# cocos2d+box2d disable gravity to separate bodies

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

Now my project included gravity for the world. But now you want to disable gravity for certain objects.
Now I'm doing this:

```
void GameScene::initPhysics()
{
    CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    b2Vec2 gravity;
    gravity.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
    world = new b2World(gravity);

    // Do we want to let bodies sleep?
    world->SetAllowSleeping(true);

    world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);
}
```

Prompt how to turn off gravity for a particular object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [b2Body class](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/2.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html#a8e66a570c2aeee93b29d84cae861a612) has a `gravityScale` property. Call `body->SetGravityScale(0.0)` on every body that you don't want to be affected by gravity.

Comment: Could you tell me SetGravityScale in cocos2d js?

Answer (score 0):

set  body->setGravityEnable(false);